# How to automate Outlook with C++ in VS 2012 Express?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, outlook, visual-studio-express

I'm developing a C++ app in Visual Studio 2012 Express, and one of the tasks it will need to perform is creating a new Outlook message and populating it with some template text.

[This MSDN page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220600) and [this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2575036) both give instructions for using MFC to do it, but VS 2012 C++ Express doesn't support MFC.

I have to use C++ for this app because it calls a C-based API and making these API calls directly from C# without a C++ wrapper has proven impractical.

I know I can do this by exporting the C++ code as a DLL and then importing that into a C# .NET app that uses Interop to control Outlook, but I was thinking it would be simpler if I just did it all in C++.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far I've found this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200174